# How to troubleshoot unresponsive IE10 after boot?

Tags: networking, windows-8, internet-explorer-10

Anyone got an idea on how  to troubleshoot this?

Internet Explorer 10, both desktop and modern-UI version is unresponsive for 2 minutes right after reboot/startup/wake of a Windows 8 Pro machine with Intel LAN and WLAN adapters.

During the first 2 minutes after startup of the machine IE seems to freeze, unable to access the network. Other applications can access the network and Google Chrome also works right from the start, only IE seems to freeze for a timeout of about 2 minutes.

I have ran out of ideas on how to find the issue after trying a lot of stuff like disabling all extensions in IE and disabling applications with automatic startup. None of this seems to help.
Cannot find any messages that are related to the issue in event logs either. 
The problem started occuring a few weeks back but was not an issue before that.

Comment: It's rare for a Windows box to not be pretty unresponsive for several minutes after boot.  This is one of many reasons it's called "Windoze".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might be a problem with Google Chrome iFrame.

Try these steps:

A)**Uninstall and re-install Chrome web browser then check for the issue.**

If the issue persists then perform a clean boot to check if any third party applications or start-up items are causing the issue, as clean boot helps in eliminating software conflicts.

B)**Clean boot**

By setting your system in clean boot state helps in identifying if any third party applications or startup items are causing the issue.

- Press the `Windows + R` keys on the keyboard.
- In the Run windows type `MSCONFIG` and click OK.
- Click the Boot tab and uncheck Safe Boot option.
- On the General tab, click to select the option Selective startup,
  and then click to clear the option Load startup items check box.
- On the Services tab, click to select the Hide all Microsoft
  services check box, and then click Disable all.
- On the StartUp tab, click Open Task Manager. In the Task Manager
  window under startup tab, right click on each startup item which
  are enabled and select Disable.
- Click OK, and then click Restart.

B.1)**Enable half of the services**

- Press the `Windows + R` keys on the keyboard.
- In the Run windows type `MSCONFIG` and click OK.
- Click the Services tab, and then click to select the Hide all
  Microsoft services check box.
- Click to select half of the check boxes in the Service list.
- Click OK, and then click Restart.

B.2)**Enable half of the Startup items.**

If no startup item causes this problem, a Microsoft service most likely causes the problem. To determine which Microsoft service may be causing the problem, repeat step B.1 and step b.2 without selecting the Hide all Microsoft services check box in either step.

After you have finished troubleshooting, follow these steps to boot to normal startup.

- Press the Windows + R keys on the keyboard.
- In the Run windows type MSCONFIG and click OK.
- On the General tab, click the Normal Startup option, and then click
  OK.
- When you are prompted to restart the computer, click Restart.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I found that it is somehow related to the HTTP Proxy Discovery. After experimenting with the services and startup stuff I finally got it working instantly after boot by unchecking the Automatically detect settings checkbox in Connection -> LAN settings in Internet options.

Answer (score 0):

Run Resource Monitor, select the hanging IE and [rightclick and select on "Analyze Wait Chain"](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/sasha/archive/2009/04/18/wait-chain-traversal-in-windows-7-resource-monitor.aspx):

[image]

What do you see? Why does IE hang?

Comment: In fact it doesn't report any problems, it says IE is running normally.

Comment: Very nice troubleshooting feature that I didn't know about before, even if it didn't report any issues this time!